# Product URL going on 404 page after data migration in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration

After Data Migration M1=>M2 (1.9.2.4=>2.2.6). Add to cart and Product Page is not working. Product Page Url is going on 404 page. Please Help me if any one have solution.

Answer (score 0):

404 product page url redirection and add to cart issue is resolved. data migration is not completed correctly so, I have again migrated data and now it's working fine.